# Why does my application.js file cause my Heroku deployment to fail?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, heroku, deployment

I'm on Rails 6 and I'm using Bootstrap and I keep running into this error when deploying to Heroku

The solution has been to comment out the "import 'stylesheets/application'; from my application.js folder in my app/javascript/packs folder. 
Here's my application.js file:

```
import Rails from '@rails/ujs';
import Turbolinks from 'turbolinks';
import * as ActiveStorage from '@rails/activestorage';
import 'channels';
// import 'stylesheets/application';
import 'controllers';
import 'bootstrap';
import 'tom-select';

require('utilities/tom_select');
require('trix');
require('@rails/actiontext');

Rails.start();
Turbolinks.start();
ActiveStorage.start();

window.initMap = function(...args) {
  const event = document.createEvent('Events');
  event.initEvent('google-maps-callback', true, true);
  event.args = args;
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Here's the error from the deployment:

```
 ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss
remote:        Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
remote:        ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
remote:        ParserError: Syntax Error at line: 1, column 38
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss:6:65128
remote:            at Parser.error (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:127:11)
remote:            at Parser.operator (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:162:20)
remote:            at Parser.parseTokens (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:245:14)
remote:            at Parser.loop (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:132:12)
remote:            at Parser.parse (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-values-parser/lib/parser.js:51:17)
remote:            at parse (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:47:30)
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:333:24
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:194:18
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:139:18
remote:            at Rule.each (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:105:16)
remote:            at Rule.walk (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:135:17)
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:152:24
remote:            at Root.each (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:105:16)
remote:            at Root.walk (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:135:17)
remote:            at Root.walkDecls (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss/lib/container.js:192:19)
remote:            at transformProperties (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:330:8)
remote:            at Object.syncTransform [as plugin] (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-custom-properties/index.cjs.js:522:5)
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-preset-env/index.js:459:97
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:316:20
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
remote:            at context.callback (/tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
remote:            at /tmp/build_163c57ff/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js:208:9
remote:         @ ./app/javascript/packs/application.js 5:133-165
```

I've googled about 15 different Stackoverflow and Github issues with no resolution outside of commenting out that line, but without that link my javascript isn't getting added and thus my site isn't formatted properly.

Has anyone run into similar issues and found a solution?

Comment: Could you also post your `application.scss` file, or maybe the first lines?

Comment: There's a syntax error in your `application.scss` file on line 1.

Comment: `@import 'bootstrap';
@import 'tom-select/dist/css/tom-select.bootstrap5';
@import './actiontext.css';
`